# XMIDI file format

Tags: language-agnostic, midi

I am going to write a converter from Miles Sound System Extended MIDI to standard MIDI file, but I am unable to find any good documentation on this format. There is a DOS converter at http://www.hitsquad.com/smm/programs/xmi2mid/, but it is useless on 64-bit platforms and there aren't any sources of this program. There is also John Miles' website http://www.ke5fx.com/ where older AIL Version 2 is, but my C and assembly language capabilities aren't good enough to understand it. I have found a converter in Java at http://de.glibly.de/?site=software&lang=eng, but it has strange tempo issues and I haven't found a way to fix it yet. Could you point me to some documentation or a working converter with sources, preferably in C#?

Comment: Why is the DOS version useless on 64-bit platforms?  Just run it inside [DOSBox](http://www.dosbox.com), then you can use it on Win/Mac/Linux/etc.

Comment: FYI, there is some documentation about the XMIDI format nested within the AIL 2 release from Miles' website that you refer to.

Comment: @JohnGlassmyer Thanks, but I also had found the AIL documentation, and it didn't tell much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only completely working converter I've found so far is the in_midi.dll plugin of WinAmp.